# Losing image format when resizing with PIL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image

myImg = request.FILES['docfile']
myImg = Image.open(myImg)
print(myImg.format, myImg.size, myImg.mode)
myImg = myImg.resize((50, 50))
print(myImg.format, myImg.size, myImg.mode)
```

Here is an abridged version of a (django/ python 3.5) code. The goal is to resize an image (i don't want to use thumbnails for this), but keep it in memory, not save it to disk (yet) since I must pass it back into array.

Anyway, here are the results of the 2 prints:

```
PNG (1300, 1300) RGBA
None (50, 50) RGBA
```

As you can see, the format is lost after the resize. How can I preserve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the doc [says](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.format):

> **`PIL.Image.format`**
>
> The file format of the source file. For images
>   created by the library itself (via a factory function, or by running a
>   method on an existing image), this attribute is set to `None`.

After you resize the image it becomes “created by the library”, so if you want to preserve the format, you have to do this explicitly.

Also note that *format* is the property of the source file, not the image itself. The image itself is just an abstract set of pixels stored in the memory in some way. So it makes no sense to ask what is the format of an *image*. It makes sense to ask what is the format of a *file* which contains an image. So the image has no format until you write it to a file (or encode into some format for this purpose).

Comment: If you are using the original Python Imaging Module instead of the Pillow fork, the link to the documentation is http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.format

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. And how would I encode the image back to PNG ? Forcing format to PNG shows "PNG" indeed, but image is still of style <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=50x50 at 0x105D224A8> instead of being "imagename.png". Is there any way to do this in memory ?

Comment: @RobertBrax Well, you have to actually call `.save(output, format='PNG')` on it. If you want to save into memory, I guess you should try to pass [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) as `output` instead of a real file.

Comment: Thanks I did so. Image now is a true png on disk. But when I reopen it with open(BASE_DIR + '/' + myName) it is of type <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=50x50 at 0x1055FA278> instead of myName.png which seems to cause problem with what I try to do. Isn't it possible for the image not to be a PIL image ?

Comment: @RobertBrax I’m not sure, I understand your question. The type of the image is its type, the name of the file is its name. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember items in `FILES` collection is like streams, i.e. once read you must set position to the beginning again. For example, you could load content to `StringIO` object, then create image from it, then call `seek(0)` on it and create thumbnail from that object again.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the format, you could do:

```
myImg = Image.open(myImg)
myImg2 = myImg.resize((50, 50))
myImg2.format = myImg.format
```